# Using a MicroSD Card as a VM Harddrive, on mac

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, sd-card

My aging MacPro is well, aged :) and dying. I don't want to buy another but rather use my new Macbook Pro. The only problem is a massive lack of storage. I'm used to 6x drives, all SSD.

Right now the MBP has a 128GB SSD which is fine for it. I want to run my Win8 VMs on this mac and was thinking of keeping them on a 64GB MicroSD (MicroSDXC Class 10 UHS-1 30MB/s Memory Card).

Since the VM isn't on all the time it seems like the SD might make it ... So my questions are really, can a SD card even handle the load of running an OS? what others problems might arise doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this isn't possible. It works sure but the SD cards are just too slow to run a VM and I was using something super lean and it still struggled. I used the fastest MicroSDXC/HC card at 64GB from SanDisk. My only solution was to upgrade the primary SSD to something bigger and that worked out well.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this for my Macbook AIR 128GB SSD. The problem is that you can't upgrade the harddrive. My Windows XP VM is 30GB and I was using VMWare 3 (I will have to upgrade it to version 5 for OSX Mountain Lion). Was also concerned if the SD card would sit securely or pop out if a coffee mug bumped into it. I have yet to use an SD card so it might not be a problem. I suppose maybe I could move other things to the SD card though and keep my vm on the main drive?

Comment: yeah but the SD cards aren't fast enough - no real solution, hack the machine for a bigger SSD which are cheaper now or upgrade the mac :)